# Loggin' try-catch transactions

Tags: php, pdo, transactions, try-catch

My code is

```
                try{
                $this->_db->beginTransaction();
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("...");
                $stmt->execute(array($var1, $var2));
                                    ...

            } catch (Exception $e) {
              $stmt->rollBack();
            }
```

I want to log this action to my log file with a function

as you see this one meant to save errors in transaction. Another one should also save the succeeded attempts. BUT if I put them inside of try{} and catch{} they not working for some reason. outside it does work good but I'm not sure what exactly should I check here for true/false to see the result outside of try/catch.

### Thanks for your answers. I'm just learning so my questions might be stupid. Sorry for this. =)

Update.

What I've tried to do is:

```
try{...
} catch (Exception $e) {
$stmt->rollBack();
file_put_contents(LOG_CONST, date("r")." UderID: ".$id." Error: ".$e->getMessage()."\n", FILE_APPEND);            
}
```

And it didn't put anything.

---

Update 2

Not sure if I have to add a new details here or I should answer to myself... Anyway. Right now I'm trying this code

```
try{
$this->_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->_db->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare

         ..................

    $stmt->execute(array($var));
        file_put_contents(DATACHANGE_LOG, date("r")." ".n307." UderID: ".$id."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    $this->_db->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
        file_put_contents(DATACHANGE_LOG, date("r")." Hello! \n", FILE_APPEND);
        $stmt->rollBack();
}
```

I have a same result with valid and not valid data at my log file. It's the first row from try{} which means that rollback is not affective at file_put_contents. However if the data at queries not valid rollback working agains them and there is no changes at DB. But the row before rollback never works.

Errors are enabled but it doesn't show anything... I just can't give up I have to understand it...

---

Update 3

What is invalid data?
I've tried MySQL errors/table,row errors.
Why do I need this at all?
I'm learning and doing a lot of things that I don't need actually just to understand how it works. As I see now it throwing errors in MySQL itself so really not useful logger in this particular case. Anyway I've got my errors and here is it.

Working code:

```
                try{
                $this->_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->_db->beginTransaction();
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare

                                     QUERIES

                $stmt->execute(array($var));
                file_put_contents(DATACHANGE_LOG, date("r")." ".n307." UserID: ".$id."\n", FILE_APPEND);
                $this->_db->commit();
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                file_put_contents(DATACHANGE_LOG, date("r")."Error". $e->getMessage()."  UserID: ".$id."\n", FILE_APPEND);
                if($this->_db->rollback())
                    header("Location: http://link");
            }
            header("Location: http://anotherlink");
```

Comment: You know, it's hard to tell why some code doesn't work if it is written in the form "I put something somewhere".

Comment: Try to put file_put_contents above rollback and turn error reporting on

Comment: May be you just didn't set proper error mode, see here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: What is "not valid data"? What debugging have you tried? Why writing to files if you don't know if your system even works? Why not to echo errors out? Do you have an exception thrown or not? Answer this question before writing to files

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing essentially different inside try..catch blocks. And your file writing code should be working the same way as outside, no difference.

The only issue I can think of is irrelevant to try..catch but to exceptions in general: a thrown exception terminates further code execution. Say, if there is an error in `$stmt->rollBack();` - no code below will be executed. So, it's better to move a logger at the top of the block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see the update of main post. Still no result for me. BTW which errors should be there? I've tried with a wrong table names and values.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've got how to make it work even if I don't need it still good practice. I've read a lot of info about Exceptions today.